# ABP Custom Filter - How to select/Hide Parent element

Tags: css, adblock

I want to know if there is a way to hide parent element of an identified element.

for example:

```
<div>
<span id="abx">some garbage content</span>
<div>other garbage containers not having any class or id</div>
</div>
```

The custom filter of **AdBlockPlus** to select `abx` will be:

```
##span#abx
```

But how to select its parent element? because we need to hide all siblings of identified element.

Comment: (moving this as a comment) It may be possible to find a workaround by looking at the problem from a different angle.

E.g. 
If all your other divs have id or class, you could filter them out like

    div:not([class]):not([id])

Answer (score 9):

**You can't do that**, because of limitations of CSS 3.

It will be possible after implementation of the [relational pseudo-class: :has()](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#has-pseudo) from *Selectors Level 4*, with following syntax:

```
example.com##div:has(> #abx)
```

[Current support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) for this feature.

Comment: Are there any browsers that currently let you do that with AdBlockPlus?

Comment: @orrd: None I know about.

Comment: @orrd #?#div:-abp-has(span###abx)

Comment: I'm happy to announce that it's now possible:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Answer (score 4):

You can use an AdblockPlus CSS selector.

```
#?#div:-abp-has(span###abx)
```

https://help.adblockplus.org/hc/en-us/articles/360062733293-How-to-write-filters#elemhide-emulation

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible using relational pseudo class :has but it is not currently supported.

- https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#relational
- http://css4.rocks/selectors-level-4/relational-pseudo-class.php

(Subject selector is removed from specification:
http://css4.rocks/selectors-level-4/subject-of-selector.php)

This feature has not been part of CSS before because of [performance](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors).

There is polyfill in [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/769).